# Android studio,, AVD emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with avd emulator. It wont start, I try everything and it still doesn't work. Here is the problem:

```
"D:\Android SDK\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Slim_Shady_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:187 error 0x501 distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:187 error 0x501 TextureDraw: Could not create/link program:

emulator: device fd:584
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
ERROR: Could not create window texture: Texture dimensions are limited to 2048x2048
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Comment: Please check my answer if you still facing problem let me know

Comment: check this answer please http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282302/4919237

Answer (score 0):

1) Install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) from the Android SDK Manager

[image]

2) Run (for Windows):

{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe

or (for OSX):

{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\IntelHAXM_1.1.1_for_10_9_and_above.dmg

3) Start the emulator

Comment: I had already done that. Setting is 512mb. I think HAXM is ok. It prints: HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

Comment: please check this answer                      https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/error-hax-is-working-and-emulator-runs-in-fast-virt-mode-emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered

Comment: OK. Now it's printing:                                                                                   draw: no program
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6

Comment: please add screenshot so i can easily understand your problem

Comment: Hey did you fixed your Issue or still facing problem.if you still facing problem provide screen short of console output so i can easily understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you own an android phone or tablet, then you can install the .apk of your app on it. You can find the apk here AndroidStudioProjects\AppName\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk