# error in android studio log cat need help..open gl FBO not found

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

```
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6 ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6 distrib/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:2095 error 0x501 distrib/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1512 error 0x501 distrib/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1512 error 0x501
```

What does this mean?

Comment: when iam trying to open emulator i see this...

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087643/android-studio-avd-emulator